# Find missing items in a list based on a mask

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to figure out if this is possible in c#. I have a list of values (barcode strings) say:

```
11Y111
22Y222
33Y333
44Y444
66Y666
```

and I want to identify which items were not scanned (not in the list. in this case 55Y555).  The problem is the barcode could be anything: just numeric, or with one or more alpha chars in it - ie A123456, 123456A etc.  It will be the same barcode mask each time the scan takes place however.

Can anyone think of a possible way to search the resulting string based on the barcode mask to determine which items were not in the list?  I thought about regex but could not come up with anything.

Any help appreciated!

Jim

Comment: I don't get it - how would a regex match something that is not there? Do you have a list of the expected values and want to check against that?

Comment: I did not know if it was possible in regex. No, I do not have a list of expected values other than a starting barcode say A123456 and an ending barcode say A444444. But the problem is that a char may appear anywhere in the barcode - e.g. BC123456 123456BC 12BC3456.

Comment: You can solve this with regex otherwise you can as said in the answer below just remove all the letters and then just itterate through them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexes aren't going to solve this problem - they can only match something that is there, not something that is missing. I'll suggest a different approach:

- Take your list of values.
- Remove the letters from them, leaving only the digits (something like  `resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\D+", "");`).
- Iterate over a list of numbers in the range you're expecting (e. g. from 123456 to 444444) and keep/print the ones that can't be found in your list.

Comment: Thanks Tim - must be a slow day, I could not think of a way ;)